# "einige zehn" - Gibt es das (noch)?

Tags: usage

Ich würde diesen Ausdruck gern in der Kundenkommunikation verwenden. Ich finde ihn gerade passend, weil er (meines Erachtens) semantisch eine kleinere Anzahl ausdrückt (auf Zeit bezogen) als z.B. der Ausdruck "ca. eine halbe Stunde".

Bei einer Google-Suche finde ich zwar einige zehn Treffer in Wörterbüchern und Übersetzungshinweise, aber eigentlich nichts zum Thema, wie gebräuchlich diese Angabe heutzutage ist.

Ich denke, jeder (native Speaker) wird verstehen, was gemeint ist, oder liege ich falsch?

Was meint ihr?

Comment: Meinst Du so etwas wie "einige zehn Minuten"? Oder was genau?

Comment: Als Deutscher wünsche ich mir konkretere Zeitangaben als „irgendwas zwischen 20 und 90 Minuten“. :) Daher rate ich von der Formulierung ab.

Comment: "Einige Hundert Euro" gibt's natürlich. "Einige Dutzend Eier" auch. "Einige Zehn Schrauben" würde deshalb auch verstanden werden. *Gebräuchlich* ist es deshalb aber nicht.

Comment: Einige verallgemeinert das Ganze was nicht falsch ist doch etwas schwammig. Was @Roland Illig schon erwähnt hat, dass Deutsche lieber genaue Angaben haben wollen stimmt schon häufig sogar 'überkorrekt'. Aber gerade wenn du andeutest, dass du das in der Kundenkommunikation  anwenden möchtest rate ich dir eher davon ab. Auf mich würde es einen etwas schlechten Eindruck machen und ist eventuell eher angebracht bei Unerfahrenen Klienten bzw für Marketingzwecke (der breiten Masse).

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/35053/1696).

Comment: @Ingmar direkt ja, einige zehn Minuten. Aber mich interessiert der Ausdruck auch im absoluten Sinn.

Comment: Mir fehlt auch der Hinweis auf "Minuten" - einige Viertelstunden ist ja auch zitbezogen. Weniger als eine halbe Stunde kann aber "einige Zehn Minuten" schlecht ausdrücken. Wenn es mehrere sind, müssen es mindestens 2 sein, also 20 Minuten. Wenn dann "ca. 20 Minuten" nicht gewählt wird, scheint es dafür Gründe zu geben. "Einige" würde ich normalerweise, wg. des 10er-Systems, als 3-9 auffassen, aber sehr kontextabhängig ("Wir hatten einige Biere", "Geben Sie einige Ringe Lauch in den Quark") - wegen des abweichenden Zeitsystems aber zu 20-60 Minuten tendieren.

Comment: X-bis-Y-Minuten ist wahrscheinlich der bessere Ausdruck. Dass "einige 10 Minuten" als "weniger als eine halbe Stunde" aufgefasst wird, würde ich verneinen. "Weniger als eine halbe Stunde" könnte überhaupt der Ausdruck sein, den Du suchst, den Wald vor Bäumen nicht findend.

Comment: @swe "Einige zehn" ist umgangssprachlich eigentlich "-zig", aber das würde ich nicht in der Kundenkommunikation verwenden. "Das benötigt einige -zig Minuten." bedeutet dann dass es zwan **-zig**, dreis **-zig** oder vier **-zig** Minuten braucht. Ich halte es für eher umgangssprachlich, habe es aber in der Bedeutung und Nutzung schon ein paar Mal in der Zeitung gelesen.

Answer (score 2):

Im allgemeinen sagt man "einige Dutzend / ein paar Dutzend", wenn man eine Menge zwischen 20-100 beschreiben will.

Speziell bei Minuten wäre das aber sehr ungewohnt, da würde man eher von Stunden ausgehen und sagen "etwa eine viertel / halbe / dreiviertel Stunde".

Comment: Er will eine kleiner Zeitspanne als 30 Minuten ausdrücken.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt *zig* (as part of *zwanzig*, *dreißig*, *vierzig* etc.) Möglichkeiten, so etwas auszudrücken, würde ich sagen - aber wohl niemals schreiben.

Answer (score 0):

Die Kombination "einige + Zahl" gibt's nur formelhaft ab *Hundert* über *Tausend*, *Millionen*, usw. aufwärts, oder mit Mengenwörtern wie *Dutzend*, *Paare*, oder auch Einheiten wie *Dezimeter*.

Helfen würde hier vielleicht "einige Zehnminuten-Einheiten".

Comment: gibts für die Behauptung "ab Hundert..." irgendeine belastbare Quelle?

Comment: das kann ich dir nur als Muttersprachler so sagen

Comment: danke, Muttersprachler bin ich auch :)

Comment: @swe: Dann muss ich mich aber sehr über deine Frage wundern! Dass einige zehn nicht geht, ist eigentlich jedem Deutschen klar

Comment: @äöü hm, in meinen Ohren klingt es ehr ziemlich elegant... Aber darum fragte ich ja nach anderen Meinungen